# How to find an Object with primary key is string on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I has a table Reading(ID:string(8),title:string(100),contents:text)
And in Reading models:

```
class Reading < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "reading"
  self.primary_key = :ID
end
```

In reading controller

```
private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_reading
      @reading = Reading.find(params[:ID])
    end
```

I have a record of reading table with ID is "20150910".

But `Reading.find("20150910")` not work.

Comment: Can you post your `params` coming into your actions?

Comment: The param is only ID with value "20150910"

Comment: Add server log to your question. It would be helpful

Comment: Thanks @JAL, `Reading.find(params[:ID])` to Reading.find(params[:id]), its work

Comment: So it worked with `params[:id]`?

Answer (score 0):

[You should look up about `uuids`](http://rny.io/rails/postgresql/2013/07/27/use-uuids-in-rails-4-with-postgresql.html) - this is [supported by default in Rails 4](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#uuid); it's essentially the same functionality you're seeking.

We do it:

[image]

If you've set the `primary_key` in your model, and have it set in your db:

```
execute "ALTER TABLE nodes ADD PRIMARY KEY (uuid);"
```

... you should be able to use the `find` method with the passed string quite simply:

```
 @reading = Reading.find params[:id]
```

--

As stated in the comments, the issue you have could be to do with the parameter you're passing through your routes. If you're not setting `ID` explicitly, you'll have to deal with `:id`:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :readings, param: "ID"
```

Answer (score -1):

Rails expects by default for the primary key to be an int called "id" (notice the lower case). You will need to override this default and set a new primary key. Here is a helpful blog post that explains the process better than I can here: http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-override-default-primary-key-id-in-rails/

Edit: I believe the detail you might be missing is that you need to make ID unique and not null in the database.